# Approximating a Markov process by differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, markov-chains

I have a system of states, $m_S = 1, 0, -1$. After performing a certain manipulation (it can be assumed to be instantaneous), a transition can happen with probability p. However, not all states can transition into each other; $m_S = 1$ can only go to $m_S = 0$, and $m_S = -1$ can also only go to $m_S = 0$, while $m_S = 0$ can go to both states with probability p. For simplicity, lets call the states M1, M2 and M3.

Now, looking at this it is (as far as I can tell) a classic Markov chain. However, in chemistry (where one obviously has concentrations rather than discrete states) one uses kinetic rate equations, leading to a system of differential equations. Now, I don't have a very good motivation for why this would be a valid approach, but I wanted to see what would happen if I approximated my system by such kinetic rate equations, where it obviously wouldn't be a concentration of states, but more of a probability measure. (M1 + M2 + M3 = 1)

The corresponding system is

$\dot{M_1} = -pM_1 + pM_2$

$\dot{M_2} = -(2p)M_2 + p(M_1+M_3)$

$\dot{M_3} = -pM_3 + pM_2$

Now, this is readily solved by working out the eigenvalue/eigenvectors of the matrix exponential corresponding to this system, and one can thus solve for M1, M2 and M3 as functions of time.

However, this is where my intuition lets me down. At this point, I'm not sure what these differential equations tell me. I've plotted the solutions, and starting from, say, $(1,0,0)^T$, you can see that (for p = 0.05) the exponentials converge to 0.333, as is to be expected. But what kind of information can I extract from this? Can I take it quite literally, and say that after a time $t$ (for which M1 = M2 = M3) the system is completely randomized, so that any correlations due to the initial condition should be gone? Or is even this a stretch, because I'm using a continuous time variable for a discrete process?

So I suppose my question boils down to what information can be extracted from approximating a Markov chain by differential equations. I've tried looking for this, but so far I've been unsuccessful.

Comment: you are solving one of the Kolmogorov equation (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous-time_Markov_chain ), if you start with $(1,0,0)^T$, then you are saying, assuming your have 1 particle starting at the first position, there is $M_i(t)$ probability such that the probability you will find the particle in $i$th state at time $t$ is $M_i(t)$

Comment: regardless where you start, $M(t)$ should converge to the equilibrium distribution. which is obtained by solving $0 = \lambda P$.

Comment: Hm, yeah that makes sense. If I have a dataset from an experiment of such a process, what kind of information could I extract from it using this model? Would it be possible to find p, or maybe only determine if p is indeed equal for each transition (and if not, their ratio's?)
And can I indeed say something about correlation times?

Comment: so you have data you want to fit the data to this model? what is the data?

Comment: Yes, I have data of a certain variable going from 1 to 0.5 to 0 (corresponding to M1, M2 and M3) governed by the process described above. I have about, say, 20000 of these points.

Comment: This is data taken per second or something? You have discretised a continuous markov chain, if that is the case

Comment: Uhm, as far as this data set goes it can be seen as a discrete dataset. The data is the spin state of an atom at a certain time, and it is measured every x microseconds, where every measurement has a chance of flipping the spin with probability p. I'm assuming no free evolution in the x microseconds between each measurement.

Comment: I am sure there must be literature on fitting this data to a continuous time markov chain. I am not quite sure how though. I think there must be a really simple approach based on maximum likelihood